# Fatal error while getting Facebook UserData with Swift and Parse

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to add to Parse users from a Facebook LogIn.

Log In works, but then when I want to get data from the Facebook User, my App crashes saying: " fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)"
It is coming from the value of "firstName" which is nil (see code below)
Any idea why? Would be great :)

```
 var fbRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
            fbRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection, result, error) -> Void in

                if (error == nil && result != nil) {
                    let facebookData = result as! NSDictionary //FACEBOOK DATA IN DICTIONARY
                    let facebookID = (facebookData.objectForKey("id") as? String)
                    let userEmail = (facebookData.objectForKey("email") as? String)
                    let firstName = (facebookData.objectForKey("first_name") as? String)
                    let lastName = (facebookData.objectForKey("last_name") as? String)

                     var user = PFUser()

                     // println(firstName!) -> says that firstName is nil: " fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)"


                    user.setValue(firstName, forKey: "firstName")
                    user.setValue(lastName, forKey: "username")
                    user.setValue(facebookID, forKey: "objectID")
                    user.setValue(userEmail, forKey: "email")




                    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {  .... }
```

I have absolutely no idea how to fix this, so any help would be great ! :)

PS: this code is in the

```
    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give parameters with key **fields**

```
 if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, email, first_name, last_name"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){


                let email = result.valueForKey("email") as? String       
                let fbid = result.valueForKey("id") as! String
                let fname = result.valueForKey("first_name") as! String
                let lname = result.valueForKey("last_name") as! String

            }
        })
    }
```